# Where are people registering on my website?

Tags: user-registration

I'm getting tons of spam from people registering on my site, but there is no place to register. I did check `http://MyWebsiteName.com/wp-login?action=register`, but it said "Page not found," so that's not it. Where and how are they registering?

I unchecked the box "Anyone can register" under general settings. Just can't figure out how spammers are getting in.

Comment: Can you elaborate, maybe provide the URL (i can respect being weary of that) but otherwise you will be more receiving a shot at the dark as opposed to a definitive answer.Also does your theme or any plugins create a custom registration form?

Answer (score 1):

My research: "By default, WordPress websites allow for user registrations from a  specific link: http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=register. These spambots are programmed to go looking for that link to register fake users."

So, your first step is to change the login page from wp-login.php to something else. Unfortunately, this is not the easiest thing to do by yourself. But fortunately, there are many plugins that will help you do this; one is the Better WP Security plugin, described here https://managewp.com/change-your-wordpress-login-url . (Find others by looking in the plugin directory for 'registration spam'.)

Haven't dug into the `wp-login.php` code for hooks to change things, that's is a bit beyond this answer. A plugin that has already done the work might be a better choice, unless you like 'reinventing the wheel'.

It is also possible that an htaccess that checks for that specific URL and looks for a referring page on your site might work. But that is not entirely foolproof, as a spammer can spoof the referring page. One of the many existing 'stop registration spam' plugins might be easiest for you.